# how associate the current_user on more 2 models on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to associate the `current_user` when I associate this objects on Bar create, another thing, is this way right? Or should I do this on type controller?

#### Model Bar

```
belongs_to :type
belongs_to :user
```

#### Model Type

```
has_many :bars
```

#### Model User

```
has_one :bar
```

#### Bar Controller

```
def new
  @bar = Bar.new(:type_id => @type.id)
end

def create
  @bar = current_user.build_bar(params[:bar].merge(:type_id => @type.id))
  if  @bar.save     
  flash.now[:success] = "wohoo!"
    render  :edit
  else
    render  :new 
  end
end
```

Comment: from where `@type` came from inside controller action?

Comment: from bar! table_bar = type_id, user_id!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the general Rails approach to creating a model through an association - assuming that current_user is set during login or elsewhere and @type is set appropriately in a `before_filter`.

In the `Bar Controller`:

```
def new
  @bar = current_user.bar.build
end

def create
  @bar = current_user.bar.build(params[:bar].merge(:type_id => @type.id))
  if  @bar.save     
    flash.now[:success] = "wohoo!"
    redirect_to @bar
  else
    render  :new 
  end
end
```

Building through the association in this way will automatically set the `user_id` field on bar to the `current_user.id`.

Note also that you will likely want to `redirect_to` rather than `render` on the success case. If you want to go to edit directly then user `redirect_to edit_bar_path(@bar)`. If you want to see more info about why then check out the [Layouts and Rendering Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) which discusses render v redirect and the implications of each.

Comment: thank's man! but now show this error undefined method `bars' for #<User:0x007fd78da57cd0>

Comment: Sorry - missed the singular on the User model that it `has_one :bar`. The correct code should be `current_user.bar.build`. I will update the answer above.

Comment: yeah! almost there, now i have another error, but finally i realized what is happening. thanks man!